# Chess program OO design

Tags: python, oop, chess

In my chess program, I have a class called Move. It stores where the piece was taken and put. What was the piece and what was the piece captured.

The problem is though, in order to get the piece that was moved and captured, I pass the whole Board object to the __init__ method. And so IMO it seems like I should store all the Move class methods to the Board class instead, which too has a method that get's the piece on a given square.

I'm just beginning to learn OO, so some advice regarding this, and maybe some more general design decision is much appreciated.

Here's the Move class that I feel might better be omitted?

```
class Move(object):

    def __init__(self, from_square, to_square, board):
        """ Set up some move infromation variables. """
        self.from_square = from_square
        self.to_square = to_square
        self.moved = board.getPiece(from_square)
        self.captured = board.getPiece(to_square)

    def getFromSquare(self):
        """ Returns the square the piece is taken from. """
        return self.from_square

    def getToSquare(self):
        """ Returns the square the piece is put. """
        return self.to_square

    def getMovedPiece(self):
        """ Returns the piece that is moved. """
        return self.moved

    def getCapturedPiece(self):
        """ Returns the piece that is captured. """
        return self.captured
```

Comment: An entire *class* dedicated to piece motion?  I don't agree with that design...it would be far more effective to create a superclass of `Piece`s, have a `move()` function there, and overwrite it to suit the different types of pieces.

Comment: Oh, and I'm aware of another question that has about the same question, but there was an answer written in Java and I couldn't quite follow it. But from there, I got the idea of a move class.

Comment: To clarify a bit:  Objects represent nouns, like a book or a board or a television.  Methods represent verbs, like read, move/place, or watch.

Comment: I read about the idea of Move as a class, and it made a bit sense to me, as the answerer explained, when doing move generation or searching, i can have a list of Move objects to represent all of the moves and the relevant information about them. 
Oh, i'm sorry, i don't quite understand why are you talking about nouns and verbs, it might be because my English isn't the best.

Comment: @Makoto -- having a class to represent a move isn't necessarily a bad idea.  You could create a list of moves which would basically be all the information you need to re-construct an entire game.  (This also makes `undo/redo` functionality much easier).  In other words, a move can in fact be a noun.  Whether or not that is desirable really depends on what features the user wants.  To simply create a playable game of chess, your proposed idea is a good one.

Comment: @mgilson:  It probably isn't a bad idea, but there are differing approaches to OO design (interestingly enough).  It would be my opinion that the `Board` would hold the state of all past moves, allowing for undo/redo functionality.  But no, there's nothing wrong with a `Move` class...it just doesn't feel canonical in OO design.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object, you are creating a *thing*.  The board and the pieces on the board are things.  When you wish to interact with these things, you require a *way* to do it - or a verb.

This is only intended as a suggested approach, to avoid the use of a `Move` class.  What I intend to do:

- Create objects that represent the board and all pieces on the board.
- [Subclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) the class that represents all pieces for individual piece motion characteristics, and [override](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) piece-specific actions, such as movement.

I begin with writing the `Board`; you can decide how to represent the locations later.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
         self.board = [['-' for i in xrange(8)] for j in xrange(8)]
    # You would have to add logic for placing objects on the board from here.

class Piece:
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
    def move(self, from, to):
         # You would have to add logic for movement.
    def capture(self, from, to):
         # You would have to add logic for capturing.
         # It's not the same as moving all the time, though.

class Pawn(Piece):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        Piece.__init__(self, name)
    def move(self, from, to):
        # A rule if it's on a starting block it can move two, otherwise one.
    def capture(self, from, to):
        # Pawns capture diagonal, or via en passant.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. But i think I'm still gonna go with my inital approach, as i've already finished much of the ChessRules class which checks if a move is legal. As i understand from your implementation, this kind of checking would have to be done inside a Pawn (or some other piece) class. 
Again, thank you!

Comment: A move actually is an (abstract) item in a chess game. We count number of moves, for example. Having each piece move itself seems obvious OOP until you try to implement it. An en passant capture, for example, depends on which piece did the previous move. A castling move depends on the history of both the king and the rook, as well as the attacked state of the intervening squares. How do the pieces know when it is allowed?

Comment: @BoPersson:  The pieces only need to know the rules of movement.  The *board* can hold state information about the pieces themselves (i.e. information about if a castle on kingside or queenside is legal, if a piece can move to another location, if a pawn can capture en passant, etc).